# TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm not working for Sharepoint Online?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, taxonomy, sharepoint-online

I want to retrieve items from a list with a caml query where I need a taxonomy filter that contains all the child terms (by wssid). I'm able to get the items from the parent term but not its child terms.

There should be a way in sp 2010/2013 with the function [`TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getwssidsofterm.aspx)  but it seems not to work with Sharepoint Online SDK?

Included library: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy` 
Nuget package: [`Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.16.1.3912.1204`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM)

Does anyone has a solution or an alternative way? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested to get all the items recursively but this was very slow. 
I had to change my design and I'm now using SharePoint's Search functionality.